# What are Spider-Man's goggles for?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, costume, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, we're introduced to Peter's new suit, given to him by Tony Stark, which has goggles over the eyes that can change shape and color. At the end of the movie,

> when Spider-Man is fighting the Vulture in his homemade outfit, we see Peter's original goggles which also have this feature. That means that Tony thought they were useful enough to integrate into his own design.

**So what do they do, aside from allowing Spider-Man to have more expressions? What are the tactical reasons why Mr. Stark decided to implement the moving goggles into Spider-Man's suit?**

Comment: I don't see any spoilers here, but I spoilered-out the part which seemed most spoilery. Please feel free to change it in any way you like (though I'd avoid things like [SPOILER] in title).

Comment: @Gallifreyan Really? I thought that was appreciated?

Comment: As per [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/980/70236), we prefer creative obscurity over blunt [SPOILER] disclaimers. Also they're ugly.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Thanks for that. :) I was going off of what I've seen in the feeds. I guess I caught them before they were changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### It helps him focus

From a transcript of the film Captain America: Civil War

> Tony Stark: Lordy! Can you even see in these?
> Peter Parker: Yes. Yes, I can! I can. I can-I can see in those. Okay? It's just that... when whatever happened, happened... it's like my senses have been dialled to 11. There's way too much input, so... they just kinda help me focus.

Evidently, Peter has included them to help him see, and Tony has kept them because he realises he needs them even after the upgrade.

#### Out-of-universe

Gives the character some expression and emotion and makes it more humanly and therefore easier to relate to.

Comment: If memory serves, the quote is from _Civil War_, yes?

Comment: @Gallifreyan fixed

Comment: What about when "Instant Kill" mode is activated? They completely close save for a tiny opening that turns red. That doesn't seem like enough for him to see through.

Comment: No clue. Wait for the next film or some interviews in the future or something

Comment: "Dialled to 11", as in, up to 11?

Comment: @Clockwork as opposed to down to 11?